# how to add an html button do each row in a table filled with php data?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to add an edit button to this table, the table is in html as is the button, the data is been taken out of phpmyadmin.
The error i get is:  syntax error, unexpected token "class", expecting "," or ";" in the line before $valor[accID].
This is my code:

```
<?php 

    $data = array();
    $data = popularCustomerTable();
      foreach($data AS $row => $valor){
       echo "<tr>
        <td> "<a class= "address-book-edit btn--e-transparent-platinum-b-2"; href="dashboard-customer-edit.php">Edit</a> "</td>
        <td>".$valor["accID"]."</td>
        <td>".$valor["cusName"]."</td> 
        <td>".$valor["cusEmail"]."</td> 
        <td>".$valor["cPass"]."</td> 
        <td>".$valor["cPhone"]."</td> 
        <td>".$valor["cusMailAddress"]."</td> 
        <td>".$valor["cusBillAddress"]."</td> 
        <td>".$valor["cusCity"]."</td>
        <td>".$valor["cusSate"]."</td> 
        <td>".$valor["cusCountry"]."</td> 
        <td>".$valor["cusZipCode"]."</td> 
        <td>".$valor["cusStatus"]."</td>  
        </tr>";
      }                                                                   
 ?>
```

Comment: is dashboard-customer-edit.php in the public_HTML directory on the server?

Comment: also, double -- not usually a good idea.

Comment: ahh, your quotes are all messed up.

Comment: to the first comment, don't know. To the second one will fix, thanks.

Comment: where? I was thinking that but don't know where.

Answer (score 0):

try this for the quotes:

```
echo "<tr>
    <td> <a class= 'address-book-edit btn--e-transparent-platinum-b-2' href='dashboard-customer-edit.php'>Edit</a></td>
    <td>".$valor['accID']."</td>
    <td>".$valor['cusName']."</td> 
    <td>".$valor['cusEmail']."</td> 
    <td>".$valor['cPass']."</td> 
    <td>".$valor['cPhone']."</td> 
    <td>".$valor['cusMailAddress']."</td> 
    <td>".$valor['cusBillAddress']."</td> 
    <td>".$valor['cusCity']."</td>
    <td>".$valor['cusSate']."</td> 
    <td>".$valor['cusCountry']."</td> 
    <td>".$valor['cusZipCode']."</td> 
    <td>".$valor['cusStatus']."</td>  
    </tr>";
```

Comment: would need to see the rest of the html ,oh wait, I just saw it. There's a bad quote.

Comment: ok, just updated the snippet.  try it again

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
<?php 

    $data = array();
    $data = popularCustomerTable();
    foreach($data AS $row => $valor):
?>
        <tr>
        <td>
             <a class= "address-book-edit btn--e-transparent-platinum-b-2"
               href="dashboard-customer-edit.php?id=<?php echo $valor["accID"]; ?>">Edit
             </a>
        </td> <!-- I added a an ID identifier to the link -->
        <td>"<?php echo $valor["accID"] ?>"</td>
        <td>"<?php echo $valor["cusName"] ?>"</td> 
        <td>"<?php echo $valor["cusEmail"] ?>"</td>
        <td>"<?= $valor["cPhone"] ?>"</td> <!-- Or use this way-->
        ....
        </tr>"
<?php endforeach; ?>
```